# How to return a object from Spring Flux flatmap operation

Tags: spring, flux, flatmap

I am looking to return a Mono.just(file.getAbsolutePath()) after I have saved the file.  The following is my code:

```
 public Mono<String> save(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        Mono<String> monoString = filePartMono.flatMap(filePart -> {
            File file = new File(filePart.filename());
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                LOG.info("existing file deleted: {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            Mono<Void> mono = filePart.transferTo(file);
            LOG.info("file saved: {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
            return Mono.just(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }).thenReturn("hello");
        return monoString;
```

Right now I am returning a "hello".  Is there a way I can return the file.getAbsolutePath() instead of the string out of my save() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done like this:

```
public Mono<String> save(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
    return filePartMono.flatMap(filePart -> {
        File file = new File(filePart.filename());
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
            log.info("existing file deleted: {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return filePart.transferTo(file)
            .doOnNext(v -> {
                log.info("file saved: {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
            }).thenReturn(file.getAbsolutePath());
    });
}
```